# Algebra Problem (Jaime Ros's book)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Author Jaime Ros, in chapter 6 of his book (Rethinking Economic Development), uses the set of equations 1 to 8 to find the equation (9).

\begin{equation}
    L(t) = L_m(t) + L_s(t) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{d t} L(t) = 0  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    l_m = \frac{\frac{d}{d t} L_m(t)}{L(t)} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    l_s = \frac{\frac{d}{d t} L_s(t)}{L(t)} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    n = \frac{1}{1-b} ~~~|~~~ b \in [0,1) \tag{5}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    W_{m}(t) = f\left(\frac{\operatorname{Y_{m}}{\left(t \right)}}{B \operatorname{Y_{s}}{\left(t \right)}}\right)^{- n} \operatorname{L_{s}(t)}^{- b}{} \tag{6}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{Y_m(t)}{Y_s(t)} = W_{m}(t)L_{m}(t)\left( \frac{1-\alpha s_{\pi}}{1-\alpha} \right)\frac{1}{L_{s}(t)^{1-b}} \tag{7}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    e = \frac{\frac{d x/d t}{x}}{\frac{d y/d t}{y}} = \frac{d(ln(x))/d t}{d(ln(y))/d t} = \frac{g_x}{g_y} ~~~ \forall x,y \tag{8}
\end{equation}

then (Ros equation):

\begin{equation}
    \frac{g_{Wm}}{g_{Lm}} = e = \frac{(1-l_m)}{\left[ b(l_m)+\left(n-1 \right)^{-1}\right]}
    \tag{9}
\end{equation}

The problem is that I've done the math many times and I always get the same result, which is very different from the equation (9). Following is my result:

\begin{equation}
\frac{g_{Lm}}{g_{Wm}} = \left[ \frac{-n}{n+1}+\frac{(1-b)}{n+1}\frac{g_{Ls}}{g_{Lm}} \right]^{-1}
    \tag{10}
\end{equation}

Below I detail what I did.

Replacing ({7}) in ({6}):

\begin{equation}
W_{m} = f \left(\frac{\left(1 - \alpha s_{\pi}\right) \operatorname{L_{m}}{\left(t \right)} \operatorname{L_{s}}^{b - 1}{\left(t \right)} \operatorname{W_{m}}{\left(t \right)}}{B \left(1 - \alpha\right)}\right)^{- n}  \operatorname{L_{s}}^{- b}{\left(t \right)}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}

Log-linearize and differentiate the previous function for (t):

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{W}{\left(t \right)}}{W(t)}
=
    - \frac{b \frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{L_{s}}{\left(t \right)}}{\operatorname{L_{s}}{\left(t \right)}} - \frac{n \left(b - 1\right) \frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{L_{s}}{\left(t \right)}}{\operatorname{L_{s}}{\left(t \right)}} - \frac{n \frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{W_{m}}{\left(t \right)}}{\operatorname{W_{m}}{\left(t \right)}} - \frac{n \frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{L_{m}}{\left(t \right)}}{\operatorname{L_{m}}{\left(t \right)}}
\end{equation*}

Then:

\begin{equation*}
   g_{Wm} =  - b g_{Ls} - g_{Lm} n - g_{Ls} n \left(b - 1\right) - g_{Wm} n ~~|~~g_{x} = \frac{\frac{d}{d t} \operatorname{x}}{x}
\end{equation*}
\noident solving for $g_{Wm}$ and dividing by $g_{Wm}$:

\begin{equation*}
    \frac{g_{Wm}}{g_{Lm}} = \frac{- g_{Lm} n + g_{Ls} \left(- b n - b + n\right)}{g_{Lm} \left(n + 1\right)}
\end{equation*}

knowing that $\left( n = \frac{1}{1-b}\right)$, then we can simplify the previous expression:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{g_{Wm}}{g_{Lm}} = \frac{- g_{Lm} n + g_{Ls} \left(1-b\right)}{g_{Lm} \left(n + 1\right)}
    \tag{12}
\end{equation}

From the identity $\left( L = L_m + L_s\right)$, we know that:

\begin{equation}
    g_{Ls}= \frac{-\left( g_{Lm}\right)L_m+\left( g_{L}\right)L}{L_s}
    \tag{13}
\end{equation}

Substituting the (13) equation into the equation (12):

\begin{equation*}
    \frac{g_{Wm}}{g_{Lm}} = \frac{-n}{n+1}+\frac{(b-1)}{n+1}\frac{L_m}{L_s}-\frac{(b-1)}{n+1}\frac{L}{L_s}\frac{g_L}{g_{Lm}}
\end{equation*}

inverting the previous equation:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{g_{Lm}}{g_{Wm}} = \left[ \frac{-n}{n+1}+\frac{(b-1)}{n+1}\frac{L_m}{L_s}-\frac{(b-1)}{n+1}\frac{L}{L_s}\frac{g_L}{g_{Lm}} \right]^{-1}
    \tag{14}
\end{equation}

A simplification that we can make is to consider the growth of (L) to be null ($g_L=0$):

\begin{equation}
    \frac{g_{Lm}}{g_{Wm}} = \left[ \frac{-n}{n+1}+\frac{(b-1)}{n+1}\frac{L_m}{L_s} \right]^{-1}
    \tag{15}
\end{equation}

From equations (1) and (2) we can assume that:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll|l}
      &  g_{Lm}=\frac{\dot{L_m}}{L_m}&  \text{identity} \\[15pt]
      &  g_{Ls}=\frac{\dot{L_s}}{L_s}&  \text{identity} \\[15pt]
      &  \dot{L_m}=-\dot{L_s}&  \text{if $\dot{L}=0$} \\[15pt]
     &  g_{L_m}L_m = - g_{L_s}L_s & \\[15pt]
     &  \frac{g_{Lm}}{g_{Ls}} = - \frac{L_s}{L_m}\frac{}{} & \\[15pt]
\end{array} 
\end{equation*}
\newline
\begin{equation}
    \frac{g_{Lm}}{g_{Ls}}=-\frac{L_{s}}{L_{m}}
    \tag{16}
\end{equation}

substituting (16) into (15)

\begin{equation*}
    \frac{g_{Lm}}{g_{Wm}} = \left[ \frac{-n}{n+1}+\frac{(1-b)}{n+1}\frac{g_{Ls}}{g_{Lm}} \right]^{-1}
\end{equation*}

What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: One can express $W_m(t)$ in terms of $L_m(t)$ using (6) and (7). The one can use (1) and exclude $L_s(t)$, then one can use (2) and change $L(t)$ to constant $L$. Then $W_m$ can be treated as function of $L_m$ and $e=\frac{g_{W_m}}{g_{L_m}}=\frac{L_m}{W_m}\frac{dW_m}{dL_m}$. After simplification one can obtain $e=-\frac{L_m b^2-2 L_m b+L}{\left(L_m-L\right)(b-2)}$.

Comment: Thanks. Your demonstration is much better and more concise than mine. But your final answer is the same as mine (equation 14) if we take into account that $n=\frac{1}{1-b}$ and ($g_L=0$). What I'm looking for is how to find equation (9) (if that's even possible).

Comment: I believe there must be some additional equation to go from $L_m$ to $\dot{L}_m$. Your transition from (14) to (10) is incorrect in part where you go from $\frac{\frac{\dot{L_s}}{l_s}}{L_s} -1$ to $\frac{1}{l_s}\frac{\dot{L_s}}{L}-1$ and then to $\frac{1}{l_s^2}-1$.

Comment: Thank you again. I reedited the question.

Comment: $\left( g_{Lm} = -g_{Ls}\right)$ if $g_{L}=0$. Why is that?

Comment: It was a mistake I forgot. I already adjusted.